# fields_for in rails 3 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Converting another app from Rails 2 to Rails 3 - in one of my views I have this code:

```
<%fields_for "order[commission_attributes][]", commission do |f|%>
```

This is driven from the controller action below:

```
def edit
  @order = Order.find(params[:id],:include=>[{:orderitems=>:item_schedules}, :memberids ],:order=>"orderitems.updated_at DESC")
  @active_order_iems = []
  @inactive_order_items = []
  @order.orderitems.each do |oi|
    oi_active = nil
    oi.item_schedules.each do |is|
        if (is.end_date > Date.today)
          oi_active =true
          break
        end
    end
    @active_order_iems << oi if !oi_active.nil?
    @inactive_order_items << oi if oi_active.nil?
  end

  @commissions = @order.commissions.find(:all)
  @ordertypes = Ordertype.find(:all, :order=>"description")
  @salesreps = Salesrep.find(:all, :order=>"fullname")
  @customers = Customer.find(:all, :order=>"company_name")
  @memberids = Memberid.find_all_by_customer_id(@order.customer_id)
  @products = Product.find(:all, :include=>[:items],:order=>["products.description"])
  @partners = Partner.find(:all, :order=>"company_name")
end

def get_reps
  @salesreps = Salesrep.find(:all,:order=>"fullname")
  @commission = Commission.new
  render :partial=>'commission'
end
```

In my 'order' model I then have this:

```
 def commission_attributes=(commission_attributes)
  commission_attributes.each do |attributes|
    if attributes[:id].blank?
      commissions.build(attributes)
    else
      commission = commissions.detect{|t| t.id == attributes[:id].to_i}
      commission.attributes = attributes
    end
   end
 end
```

This works in rails 2, however in rails 3 I get the error below:

```
@order[commission_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name</code></pre>
```

I can't seem to work out what the problem is, or how to work around this issue.. any help is very appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fields_for` method only takes objects or symbols. It's hard to give a specific solution without more code but something like this might work:

```
<%= form_for @order do |form| %>
  ...
  <%= fields_for @order.commission do |commission_form| %>
```

Read up on it here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: I've updated the main question, with some code from the controller and model.. if it helps?

Comment: Okay. I think `form.fields_for :commission do |commission_form|` is what you need. See how that works. As a side note, this is a good article on why it's important to keep your controllers "skinny": http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model. Also, take a look at the inherited_resources gem for controllers and simple_form (or formtastic) gem for views. They'll greatly simplify the stuff you're trying to do.

Comment: Awesome stuff! that did the trick.. I'll have a read up on that article, this app is one I've taken on from someone else - if I can clean up the code and make it easier to understand then I'm in. Thanks again for your help!.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is

```
<%= f.fields_for :commission, commission do |commission_form| %>
```

This should cause then submit to trigger `commission_attributes=` instead of messing with another model directly, and by supplying the object you can populate the form with said object.

But this is just another method worth mentioning. Here's the doc [fields_for#Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-Nested+Attributes+Examples)

Comment: I should mention I had to add ", commission" onto my form anway otherwise the existing ones didn't display their data.

Comment: That's fine, I've had a couple of situations where it made more sense to pass data through a model this way.